# Can someone explain to me why my factorial recursion code can't be compiled

Tags: c, recursion, factorial

i have made a simple program to calculate the factorial of a number. Below is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int i);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    printf("Factorial of: ");
    scanf("%i", &i);
    printf("Answer: %i\n", factorial(i));

}

int factorial(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    factorial(i) = (factorial(i - 1) * i);
    return factorial(i);
}
```

the compiler told me the following line has issues

```
factorial(i) = (factorial(i - 1) * i);
```

so i changed the above line to the following and it worked

```
int a = (factorial(i - 1) * i);
return a;
```

So, can someone explain to me why the initial line which is (factorial(i) = (factorial(i - 1) * i);) didn't work?

Comment: What would this line mean, in your opinion?

Comment: You can't assign anything to the return value of a function. That doesn't make sense. Replace the last 2 lines with `return factorial(i - 1) * i;`.

Comment: `factorial(i)` returns an integer. `factorial(i) = thing;` would call `factorial(i)`, fetch the return value and then immediately overwrite it with `thing`. Doesn't make too much sense

Comment: i have read everyone's reply and i really appreciate the help. Basically, what i did did not make sense. i am calling a function that returns a value and assigning it to the same function that returns a value. It was a mess.

Comment: ".. the compiler told me the following line has issues." [*Citation needed*] Include **the exact text** that it reported.

Answer (score 2):

```
factorial(i) = (factorial(i - 1) * i);
```

This line is invalid in terms of C standard. It is related to the `lvalue` and `rvalue` definition.

`lvalue` - is an expression referring to an object.The name 'lvalue' comes from the assignment expression `E1 = E2` in which the left operand `E1` must be an `lvalue` expression.

`rvalue` - is an expression which is not `lvalue` (I couldn't find the exact definition of it). In other word, `rvalue` cannot be re-assigned.

Example:

```
int n;
...
n = 3; // --> Legal, n is an lvalue and 3 is an rvalue
3 = n; // --> illegal, 3 is rvalue and thus n cannot be assigned to it
```

Another example

```
int a, b, c;
...

a = b + c; // --> Legal since 'a' is an lvalue (refers to an object/memory)
/* Note that 'b' is also lvalue, 'c' is also lvalue BUT 'b + c' is an rvalue expression! */
/* the temporal storage allocated for the result of the expression 'b + c' cannot be "visible" */
/* one cannot check the address of such expression: &(a + b) ==> illegal */
b + c = a; // --> Illegal
```

In you example, `factorial(i)` represents the return value of the function which is an `rvalue`.

For more details: 
https://www.embedded.com/lvalues-and-rvalues/

Answer (score 1):

Simply because you cannot give a value to a function call in C.
`factorial(i)` calls the function (which would, by the way result in an infinite recursion) and your were trying to assign a value to that call, which is not possible. In some other languages this is the way to return a value, not in C though.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in this snippet

```
    factorial(i) = (factorial(i - 1) * i);
    return factorial(i);
```

in all the places where `factorial(i)` is mentioned, it would always be interpreted as trying to call the function once more.

To fix it, introduce a temp variable:

```
    int result = (factorial(i - 1) * i);
    return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

`factorial(i) = (factorial(i - 1) * i);`

You are trying to assign an integer on the call of a function. When you write `factorial(i)` you are telling the system to call the function factorial and return a value. You can't assign a value to that value.